# How to convert the EventData to byte[]

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, azure-eventhub

I was working on upgrading the new packages in project. From  **Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging** to **Azure.Messaging.EventHubs**. so we are converting the EventData to byte[].

In **Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging**, we can convert the EventData to byte[] by using the below method.

```
eventData.GetBytes()
```

I tried in below way for converting **Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.EventData** to **Byte[]**

```
private byte[] ObjectToByteArray(Object obj)
{
    if (obj == null)
        return null;

    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    bf.Serialize(ms, obj);

    return ms.ToArray();
}
```

However I was getting below exception

> System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: 'Type 'Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.EventData' in Assembly 'Azure.Messaging.EventHubs, Version=5.8.1.0, Culture=neutral' is not marked as serializable.'

How can I do this conversion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you're looking to convert the body of an event into bytes, not perform binary formatting on the entire `EventData` instance.  If that's not the case, I'd like to understand the end-to-end scenario better.

To retrieve the body as a byte array, you would use the [EventBody](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.eventhubs.eventdata.eventbody?view=azure-dotnet#azure-messaging-eventhubs-eventdata-eventbody) property, which returns a [BinaryData](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.binarydata?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0&viewFallbackFrom=azure-dotnet) representation.  `BinaryData` offers different projections including to a raw byte array by using its `ToArray` method.

```cs
var data = new EventData(new byte[] { 0x1, 0x2, 0x3 });
byte[] bytes = data.EventBody.ToArray();
```